# Where is MYSQL installed on Mac?

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

I've always used MAMP or XAMPP to install MYSQL so it's been fairly straightforward. The only most I've had to do is create a symbolic link.

I'm now starting to learn Django and I would like to start a new. I uninstalled XAMPP and downloaded MYSQL from [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=403428) (64 bit) but I have no idea where it installed it to! I went to the command line and typed "mysql" and received the message "command not found".

Where is MYSQL installed on Mac OSX Lion?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you actually install it, or did you just download it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The installation layout is similar to that of a tar file binary
>   distribution; all MySQL binaries are located in the directory
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin. The MySQL socket file is created as
>   /tmp/mysql.sock by default. See Section 2.7, “Installation Layouts”.

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/macosx-installation.html

It's probably not added to your `$PATH`, thus why the commands aren't visible in the terminal. Try typing `echo $PATH` on your terminal to see if `/usr/local/mysql/bin` is included in the path.

Additionally, on the terminal, you can type `which mysql`. If that returns nothing your environment is not finding your MySQL binary.

Comment: +1 for it not being on your path. Try typing "echo $PATH" on your terminal to see if /usr/local/mysql/bin is on the path. Additionally, on the terminal, you can type "which mysql". If that returns nothing your environment is not seeing your MySQL installation.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried opening Terminal and typing:

> locate mysql

Comment: this wont be useful if he has never used the locate command before

Comment: locate: locate database header corrupt, bigram char outside 0, 32-127: -1