# How to get mysql running for real. basics

Tags: macos, mac, mysql

In connection with the question at:

[Where is MYSQL installed on Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/330338/where-is-mysql-installed-on-mac)

I have a question too. The widget in the startup item says mysql is running and I can use it to stop it, apparently.

But the 'which mysql" and 'locate mysql' commands do nothing.

I guess I need to learn about editing the $PATH.

IS there something funny going on? What am I missing? (besides a whole lot..?)

Even Workbench seems to indicate that it is working.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried looking in /usr/local/bin/mysql ?